# Exit Playframework application

Tags: playframework, exit, playframework-2.3

What's the best way to stop a Play application programmatically so that I get back to the `activator` console? 
(Play 2.3.7 with Java 8)

My server should exit at startup if there were initialization problems. `System.exit(1);` works, but it also quit `activator` instance, like this:

```
$ activator
[myproject] $ run

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

Initialization error. System.exit(1) would now also exit activator.
```

For development it would be more comfortable, when I would get back to the `activator` console instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go into `activator` console for running the app, instead you can use `activator run` directly in your command line.

TIP: For development it's far more comfortable to configure your IDE to start and stop the application (also for debugging). I'm using Idea with Play 2 support and it works nice.

Comment: I cannot afford a commercial license for IntelliJ at the moment :(. On slow machines it is much faster to use the `activator` console instead of using directly `activator run` multiple times. But if I get rich in the next time, I will accept this answer. ;-) (My question is not a huge problem for me, but I just wonder if there is a better solution than `System.exit` for Play.)

Comment: Thumbs up for going rich ;)